# GetComponent function returning null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I'm developing a simple game in Unity 2017 in C#.

In my levels menu I have a Text object with a button component in it, and a script attached to it.

This is what's currently in the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LevelLock : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool isLocked = true;
    private Button lvlBtn;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        lvlBtn = GetComponent<Button> ();
        if (lvlBtn != null) {
            Debug.Log ("this should be working");
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("you did something wrong");
        }
        //if(isLocked){
        //  lvlBtn.enabled = false;
        //}
    }

}
```

The problem is, that `GetComponent<Button>()` is returning `null`, meaning it's not finding the button component in the object.

I tried adding an Animator component and perform the same operation just to check and it did work, so I have no clue why it shouldn't find the button component. If anyone could help with this or point out to me something i'm doing wrong, I would really appreciate it

**EDIT**:

Inspector tab:

[image: Text object with button component screenshot]

Console tab:

[image: Inspector tab screenshot]

Comment: And you are definitely sure that a Button component exists on the object to which your script is attached?

Comment: Well yeah, I added it manually. I'm certain

Comment: Alright. I didn't mean to sound condescending, but sometimes even the most experienced developers make simple mistakes.

Comment: @JamieCorkhill I didn't take it like that. By no means i tried to be rude either lol. I know many times the answer is that simple, but I'm sure this time. I'm sorry if I seemed angry or something. On the contrary, I'm thankful you are helping me

Comment: You did not sound angry, and I did not perceive any negativity from your comment. I was merely letting you know just in case. Anyway, I will look into your issue and see if I can figure anything out.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Object the `LevelLock`  script is attached to? Also post a screenshot of the Console tab

Comment: Just tried your script on a button inside a canvas. Worked as expected. The script is correct. There must be something else that causes the trouble.

Comment: Is the Button-Object parented to the text-object or does the text-object has a component (Button-Script) on it ?

Comment: Seems like your LevelLock object have not "Button" component attached. I can't know it by sure without the screenshot of your prefab, but maybe you're trying to use the button component from "lvlButton"? which is LevelLock attribute?

Comment: I added the screenshots so you can take a look guys
@Programmer

Comment: @Bernhard The text-object has a Button-script component on it. You can check it out on the screenshots i added to the post

Comment: @Lotan I added screenshots so it's easier to see what i'm talking about

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that you attached the `LevelLock` script to the Button which is fine.

**Possible reasons and fixes**:

**1**.The component/script is not even attached to the GameObject or is attached to the wrong Object.

In, your code, calling `GetComponent<Button>();` without finding the GameObject first means that `GetComponent` should look for a `Button` component that is attached to this `GameObject` this script(`LevelLock`) is attached to.

If the script you want to retrieve, is attached to another GameObject, you can solve this by first, finding the GameObject the `Button` component is attached to with `GameObject.Find` then retrieving the `Button` component/script from it.

Replace

```
lvlBtn = GetComponent<Button> ();
```

with

```
GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("lvl 2");
lvlBtn = obj.GetComponent<Button>();
```

**3**.Script is attached to multiple Objects

One of the reasons `GetComponent<Button>()` might return `false` is because you mistakenly attached the `LevelLock` script to another GameObject. It could be an empty GameObject but that GameObject doesn't have the `Button` component attached to it.

Find this GameObject and remove the `LevelLock` script from it.

To do that, select the `LevelLock` script from the Project tab then Go to *Assets* ---> *Find References In Scene*. Remove the `LevelLock` script from other GameObjects.

[image]

This will make sure that the `LevelLock` script is only attached to the "lvl 2" GameObject

---

**3**.Multiple scripts with the-same name but in different `namespace`:

If you have two classes with the-same name but in different namespace and you attached one to the `GameObject` while trying to access the other one from code, it will be `null` since they are not the-same. I looked into your project and this was the Problem.

You created a script named *"Button"* while Unity comes with it's own built-in script/component also named *"Button"* which is in the `UnityEngine.UI` namespace.

You attached the Unity's built-in *"Button"* script to your GameObject but then  you are trying to access your own made *"Button"* script from the script. Supply the namespace which is `UnityEngine.UI` so that Unity will know that you want to use the `Button` component that comes with Unity.

Change:

```
vlBtn = GetComponent<Button> ();
```

to

```
lvlBtn = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>();
```

Also change:

```
private Button lvlBtn;
```

to

```
private UnityEngine.UI.Button lvlBtn;
```

---

Finally, **do not** name your script the-same name as any built-in component like `Button`, `Image`, `Text`, `Rigidbody` and so on. Create a `class` name and make sure that it doesn't exist with Unity API otherwise you'll continue to run into such issues and even people on SO won't be able to help you unless they have access to your project.

Comment: I just searched for more references to the script in the scene and there are no unwanted scripts attached to other objects, only on my level buttons. The thing about the second fix is that I have 5 level buttons, so I can't really use GameObject.Find("lvl 2")

Comment: If you have 5 buttons and each script is attached to each Button then make sure that so called buttons actually have a Button component. If you have tried what's in this answer and the problem is still there then zip the project and send it to me. I will take a look at it but it's very likely the problem is what's in my answer.

Comment: Would you rather i send it as a zip or to download it via git?

Comment: Upload to any file sharing service as zip then provide link here

Comment: Ok. See #3 from my edit. That was the problem. This would have been almost impossible to solve without access to your project. You can no remove the link for your project by deleting the comment above.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wouldn't have guessed it on my own, so thank you for solving it and also for that explanation. You're right it would've been impossible to solve without looking at the project

Comment: Even with your screenshot I wasn't able to tell this was the issue. This kind of problem is rare but happens. You are welcome.!

Comment: For me, simple reattaching (remove and add again) a script to a GameObject helped.